# using statement allowed in third party codebase but not in my minimal example. What am I missing?

Tags: c#, .net, openxml

I'm working on a codebase which makes use of the following construct:

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
{
    // some additional actions on spreadsheetDocument ...
    spreadsheetDocument.Close();
}
```

I'd like to add in some exception handling for invalid filenames such as the following:

```
string docPath = "asd\\da*dw.xlsx"
try
{
    using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(docPath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
    {
        spreadsheetDocument.Close();
    }
}
catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("DirectoryNotFoundException");
}
```

Suppose I create a console application, add the above to my `Main` method, add `netcoreapp3.1` as the target framework, build and then run it. The faulty filename will throw an error in the `using` statement and the exception will get caught as a `DirectoryNotFoundException`.

However, in the codebase I'm working on this doesn't get caught as a `DirectoryNotFoundException`. Instead it gets caught as an `ArgumentException`.

When I double check the project file for the third-party project I see it is using `netstandard2.0` as the target framework. When I change my own minimal working example to target `netstandard2.0` I get an error while building:

> CS8370    Feature 'using declarations' is not available in C# 7.3. Please use language version 8.0 or greater.

Which sounds like nonsense to me because the third party codebase is implementing `using` in the exact manner I have shown above. Furthermore the project files for the codebase do not explicitly set a C# language version or anything like that.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental here but I'm not sure what. Where else could the codebase be setting the language version which I might have overlooked? Is there something other than the language version which I'm missing here?

## Edit

As it turns out, I had other CS files in my so-called "minimal example" which contains `using` *statements* (as pointed out by @Marc) like the following:

```
using FileStream fs = File.Create(filename);
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.Write("test content");
    }
}
```

I was able to build the solution as expected.

However, I'm now getting a `FileNotFoundException` in my minimal example, whereas the third party app throws an `ArgumentException`.

Apparently the above is legal syntax in `netcoreapp3.1`, but not in `netstandard2.0`. When I changed all occurences of the above to the following:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(filename))
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fs))
    {
        writer.Write("test content");
    }
}
```

Comment: re the language aspect: but... that code *doesn't show a "using declaration"* - it us a "using statement" (which has existed since C# 1.2, decades ago); are you sure you're showing us the right code? however: the language-version *defaults* based on the target framework, but **can be overridden**: try adding `<LangVersion>8</LangVersion>` in the csproj properties

Comment: the `ArgumentException` vs `DirectoryNotFoundException`: that sounds like the real problem here, and is likely due to framework differences between netfx and .net "current" - perhaps just catch both? if the older runtime throws a different exception: that's not something you can fix/change/influence

Comment: @MarcGravell your comment helped me find the issue. I will edit my question to elaborate on what I was overlooking.

Comment: @MarcGravell So I fixed the build problem. I don't feel comfortable catching both errors, and would rather understand the root cause of *why* the codebase I'm working on throws one error,  while my minimal example throws a completely different error despite building against the same exact target framework...